# JavaScript - Three.js compute bounding box of Object3D with BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an `Object3D` with many levels of children (more Object3Ds or Meshes/Lines). The `Box3` class has a `setFromObject()` method which will compute a bounding box of an object and all of its descendants. This is the behavior I am looking for.

I can't use the `setFromObject()` method of `Box3`, however, because I am not using `Geometry` objects. Instead, the project I'm working on uses `BufferGeometry` exclusively. `BufferGeometry` objects do not have a `.vertices` property, which is what the `setFromObject()` function looks for when computing a bounding box.

```
var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object);
console.log(bbox.min); // x, y, and z are all Infinity.
console.log(bbox.max); // x, y, and z are all -Infinity.
```

I have also been experimenting with using the `computeBoundingBox()` method of `BufferGeometry`, but it does not seem to update the bounding box when the geometry is manipulated. I think it might be related to `matrixAutoUpdate` being `false`, but I've also tried explicitly calling `updateMatrix()` to no avail.

Is there a way to compute a bounding box on an `Object3D` and all of its descendants if using the `BufferGeometry` class? I'm new to Three.js, so any help would be appreciated!

I am using Three.js r66.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Box3.setFromObject( object )` now supports `BufferGeometry`.

three.js r.69dev (dev version)